# Modify lines in a .CSS file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to modify some lines in a .CSS file using PowerShell

I tried the following commands, but the resulting file duplicates parts of the CSS

```
 $data = foreach($line in Get-Content .\folder\bundle.css) {

  if($line -like "*.header-container{*") {
    $line -replace ".header-container{", ".header-container{display:none !important;"
  }

  if($line -like "*.header2_header{*") {
    $line -replace ".header2_header{" , ".header2_header{background-position-y: bottom !important;"
  }

  if($line -like "*.header3_header{*") {
    $line -replace ".header3_header{" , ".header3_header{background-position-y: bottom !important;"
  }
}

$data | Set-Content .\folder\bundle.css -Force
```

I would like to know what is the best way to replace different lines using PowerShell.

Comment: Can you show a sample CSS file and an example of the duplicates you're seeing?

Comment: Is that asteriks in the class definition `{*` to be taken literally?